# draggable ngx-bootstrap modal only body move and background fixed

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, draggable, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular2-Draggable](https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/home) for creating draggable modal but only content is dragging and background is fixed.

[image: problem with draggable modal]
i tried by change angular2-draggable directive selector to class ('.ngDraggable') fix this bug but it's not applied to parrent element (class='modal-dialog' role='document')

[image: modal inspect view]

I use below code to show modal:

```
this.modalService.show(OwnerAdvertisingOpportunityAddeditComponent, 
  { initialState, class: 'ngDraggable modal-lg' });
```

Any help or idea?

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question :
I solved this problem with css

```
.modal-dialog.ngDraggable {
  .modal-content {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .ngDraggable {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
  }    
}
```

But if anyone has a better solution, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use directive instead of the modal service, so that you can apply ngDraggable directly to the modal-dialog.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.show()">Open modal</button>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-static-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" ngDraggable>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">My draggable modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="myModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is modal is draggable, backdrop click will not close it.
        Click <b>&times;</b> to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```